# OpenGL version isn't equal to the supported shader version

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl-2, glew

Recently I created my own game with OpenGL and LWJGL 2 (Java). After that I wanted to improve my programming skills and I started to learn how to use OpenGL with C++.

With LWJGL I could use `#version 330` but with C++ and SDL2 I can only use `#version 110`, but `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` returns `3.0 Mesa 12.0.6`.

I initialize my window like this:

```
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 3);

SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BUFFER_SIZE, 32);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24);


m_window = SDL_CreateWindow(title.c_str(), SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, width, height, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL|SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
m_glContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(m_window);


GLenum status = glewInit();

if(status != GLEW_OK){
    std::cerr << "Glew failed!" << std::endl;
}
```

Where is my issue?

Comment: Try setting `SDL_GL_SetAttribute()` calls after `SDL_Init()` ...

Comment: What does `glxinfo | grep "shading language version"` have to say?

Answer (score 0):

You need to request an OpenGL core profile.

By default, you will get an OpenGL compatibility profile.  With a compatibility profile, you will be limited to version 3.0 if you are running on Mesa, or 2.1 if you are running on macOS.  With a core profile, you will be able to access newer versions.

This is not necessary if you are using AMD or nVidia's drivers on Linux or Windows.

In SDL, you can request a core file by adding this line before you create a window:

```
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
```

Comment: That worked partly. Now I can set `SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION` and `SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION` to 3.3 without crashing, but when I use `#version 330` in the shaders, it still throws the error, witch says that the supported GLSL versions are 1.10, 1.20, 1.30, 1.00 es, 3.00 es